# « Savoir que » plus infinitif

Tags: grammaire, infinitif, constructions

Dans la phrase ci-dessous :

> Je ne sais que vous dire Mademoiselle !

quelle est la construction grammaticale employée ?

Je sais que l'on peut omettre « pas » après « savoir » dans des phrases soutenues mais je n'arrive pas à comprendre l'emploi de l'infinitif après « que ».

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Que* est ici un équivalent soutenu de *quoi* qui n'est possible que parce que *pas* est omis. Une version plus courante est :

> Je ne sais pas quoi vous dire, Mademoiselle !

Answer (score 3):

Il s'agit ici d'une construction avec semi-auxiliaire [Grevisse, *Bon Usage* 14e ed. §§819-821, *savoir* est traité à §821 i)]. Autrement dit, le principe de base est le même que si la phrase avait été *il sait parler français*.
Ce qui complique la chose ici, c'est l'alternance possible entre *quoi* et *que* devant une interrogation indirecte dont le verbe est à l'infinitif (Grevisse, §732 b) 2°).

Par ailleurs, il tend à y avoir une nuance de sens qui fait que *je ne sais que faire* et *je ne sais pas quoi faire* ne s'emploient pas nécessairement dans les mêmes circonstances, mais il s'agit là d'une évolution encore en cours, et ici cette distinction est neutralisée.